# Is it possible to manipulate xml in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005

I have a table:

```
create table foo (id int, reportDef xml)
```

Column `reportDef` contains a long xml string.

```
<Report>
  <Criterias>
    <Criteria name="Date Range">...</Criteria>
    <Criteria name="Advertisers">
      <Elements>
        <Element name="CheckBoxOne">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Element>
        <Element name="ListViewAvailable">
          <Value>314</Value>
          <Value>57</Value>
          <Value>18886</Value>
          <Value>7437</Value>
        </Element>
      </Elements>
    </Criteria>
    <Criteria name="Revenue Types">...</Criteria>
  </Criterias>
</Report>
```

For situations where element Criteria's name attribute is "Advertisers" and element Element's name attribute is "ListViewAvailable", I want to remove Value elements where the value is 57 and 18886.  So that after I am done with processing, the XML should look like this:

```
<Report>
  <Criterias>
    <Criteria name="Date Range">...</Criteria>
    <Criteria name="Advertisers">
      <Elements>
        <Element name="CheckBoxOne">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Element>
        <Element name="ListViewAvailable">
          <Value>314</Value>
          <Value>7437</Value>
        </Element>
      </Elements>
    </Criteria>
    <Criteria name="Revenue Types">...</Criteria>
  </Criterias>
</Report>
```

Is this possible to do with SQL Server, particularly version 2005?  So far, I got the query to extract the available values, but no idea where to proceed with manipulation and updating the column.

```
SELECT C.value('.', 'varchar(100)'), t.id
FROM foo t
CROSS APPLY t.reportDef.nodes('
    /Report/Criterias/Criteria[@name="Advertisers"]
    /Elements/Element[@name="ListViewAvailable"]
    /Value
') Z(C)
```

Comment: Can't remove it before to generate xml? On your select statement?

Comment: @McNets The xml is already generated and is in in the database.

Comment: Have a look at Replacing values https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2738/examples-of-using-xquery-to-update-xml-data-in-sql-server/

Comment: Yes it's possible. It's also pretty difficult. Learn about XPATH syntax and SQL Server's XML update syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it this you are looking for?

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE(id INT,reportDef XML);
INSERT INTO @foo VALUES(1,
N'<Report>
  <Criterias>
    <Criteria name="Date Range">...</Criteria>
    <Criteria name="Advertisers">
      <Elements>
        <Element name="CheckBoxOne">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Element>
        <Element name="ListViewAvailable">
          <Value>314</Value>
          <Value>57</Value>
          <Value>18886</Value>
          <Value>7437</Value>
        </Element>
      </Elements>
    </Criteria>
    <Criteria name="Revenue Types">...</Criteria>
  </Criterias>
</Report>');

SELECT * FROM @foo;

UPDATE @foo SET reportDef.modify(N'delete /Report/Criterias/Criteria[@name="Advertisers"]/Elements/Element[@name="ListViewAvailable"]/Value[text()="57" or text()="18886"]');

SELECT * FROM @foo;
```

I'm afraid, that this might not work on 2005... Cannot check it at the moment...